# env step parameter in cloudbuild.yaml file not settings environment variable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-run

My `cloudbuild.yaml` file looks like

```
steps:
  # build the container image
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: ["build", "-t", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/backend:$COMMIT_SHA", "."]
    env:
      - "APP_ENV=production"
  # push the container image to Container Registry
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: ["push", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/backend:$COMMIT_SHA"]
  # Deploy container image to Cloud Run
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    args:
      - "run"
      - "deploy"
      - "backend"
      - "--image"
      - "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/backend:$COMMIT_SHA"
      - "--region"
      - "us-central1"
      - "--platform"
      - "managed"
images:
  - "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/backend:$COMMIT_SHA"
```

and it builds and deploys a new container to Cloud Run, however it doesn't set the APP_ENV environment variable to `"production"`. Why is that and how do I get it to?

I am following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
steps:
- env: [...]
```

approach sets environment variables for the Cloud Build container that runs the `docker build -t` command, so in this case only `docker build` it executes gets `APP_ENV` variable (and probably doesn't do anything with it).

You should not expect this to set environment variable for Cloud Run. For that to work, you need to specify `--set-env-vars` or `--update-env-vars` to Cloud Run in the `gcloud run deploy` step by specifying additional `args` above like:

```
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    args:
      - "run"
      - "deploy"
      ...
      - "--set-env-vars=KEY1=VALUE1"
      - "--set-env-vars=KEY2=VALUE2"
      ...
```

See https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/environment-variables#command-line to learn more or read [this article](https://ahmet.im/blog/mastering-cloud-run-environment-variables/) about alternative ways of specifying environment variables for Cloud Run applications.